# Run task before gradle resolves dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

Third time this question is asked here, and still no answer, so I'm gonna try again.

So I created a plugin that adds a new block in which I can use folders as dependencies.

So let's say I use that plugin and say:

- Project A depends on folder B (where Project B is).

The plugin then does the following:

1. It creates a task that uses GradleConnector to publish project B in maven local
2. Makes compile tasks depend on the previous task
3. adds a maven dependency using artifact, groupId, and version of project B.

Everything works like a charm except for the fact that the task is not executed before gradle resolves dependencies...

How do I get gradle to publish another project (without including it) in maven, before resolving dependencies?